# How to remember login state in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a springboot as backend,and a spa as frontend.
Now I want to remember current user's userId and permissions after login succeed. visit /current to get currentuser's info.
My controller and securityconfig below:

```
  public RespResult<Object> login() {

    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> permissions = new ArrayList<>();


    permissions.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin"));

    Long userId = (long) 122;

    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

    Authentication authentication =
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId, null, permissions);

    context.setAuthentication(authentication);

    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

    return new RespResult<Object>(200, "", null);
  }

  @GetMapping("/current")
  public RespResult<Object> getCurrentUseer() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    Long userId = Long.parseLong(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());

    System.out.println(userId);


    return new RespResult<Object>(200, "", null);
  }
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {

    String[] antMatchersAnonymous = {"/public/**", "/assets/**", "/webjars/**"};
    return web -> web.ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(antMatchersAnonymous)
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();

    return http.build();
  }

}
```

Now I can access my login controller,But I found springboot dont set cookie for frontend.
So cant remember current user's userId.
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` to set `sessionId`.

```java
  private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository = new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();

  @PostMapping("/login")
  public RespResult<Object> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest login, HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) {

    String username = login.getUsername();
    String password = login.getPassword();

    User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);

    if (user == null || !(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().matches(password, user.getPassword()))) {
      return new RespResult<Object>(201, "账号或密码错误", null);
    }

    CurrentResult currentUser = userService.getCurrentUser(login.getUsername());

    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> permissions = currentUser.getPermissions().stream()
        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Long userId = user.getId();

    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

    Authentication authentication =
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId, null, permissions);

    context.setAuthentication(authentication);

    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
    securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
    return new RespResult<Object>(200, "登录成功", null);
  }
```